# Correct way to toggle and display object contents within JSON dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So, I'm working on accessing a JSON object, within a JSON Object (not sure if it would be easier storing it as an array), in an attempt to do provide more customiztion for user selection.

I want to make it so when I select a certain type of apple (b), Then a third toggle pops up, and I can choose between weight 1, or 2, and it will populate the Weight field, the same way as when I pick another fruit or selection.

The Js fiddle contains all the code, but I'll also post the code below. 
http://jsfiddle.net/K8PcH/12/

```
 // The JSON this is all pulled from
var json = {
    "Apple": {
        "A": {
            "weight": 6,
            "price": 3.99
        },
        "B": {
            "weight": {
                "weight1": 5,
                "weight2": 12
            },
            "price": 4.99
        }
    },
    "Orange": {
        "1": {
            "weight": 4,
            "price": 4.49
        },
        "2": {
            "weight": 5,
            "price": 5.49
        }
    }
};

// Create the first dropdown
var dropdown1 = document.createElement("select");

// Populate the first dropdown
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "Select a fruit";
option.value = "none";
dropdown1.appendChild(option);

// Add options from JSON
for (var attr in json) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = option.value = attr;
    dropdown1.appendChild(option);
}

// Add the first dropdown to the page (body)
document.body.appendChild(dropdown1);

// Create the second dropdown
var dropdown2 = document.createElement("select");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "N/A";
dropdown2.appendChild(option);

// Add the second dropdown to the page (body)
document.body.appendChild(dropdown2);

// Add info field
var info = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(info);

// Function to automatically fill the weight/price fields
var auto_fill_fields = function() {

    if (dropdown1.value != "none") {
        var obj = json[dropdown1.value][dropdown2.value];
        var weight_str = "Weight: " + obj.weight + " oz";
        var price_str = "Price: $" + obj.price;
        info.innerHTML = dropdown1.value + " " + dropdown2.value + " " +  weight_str  + " " +  price_str;
    } else {
        info.innerHTML = "";
    }
};

// Handle changing the first dropdown
dropdown1.addEventListener("change", function() {
    // Remove the current options from the second dropdown
    $(dropdown2).empty();

    // Did they actually select a fruit?
    if (this.value != "none") { // Yes
        // Populate the second dropdown
        for (var attr in json[this.value]) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.innerHTML = option.value = attr;
            dropdown2.appendChild(option);
        }
    } else { // No
        // There's nothing to choose
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.innerHTML = "N/A";
        dropdown2.appendChild(option);
    }

    auto_fill_fields();
});

// Handle changing the second dropdown
dropdown2.addEventListener("change", auto_fill_fields);

// Fill in initial values

auto_fill_fields();
```

Comment: @Teemu  The Var Json is the entire json object, and weight, under the  apple category has another JSON object that I want to toggle through.

Comment: Nope, they are JS objects, which have nothing to do with data interchange formats.

Comment: @Teemu I'm confused by what you mean.

Comment: Hover over the json tag below your question ... What you have, are regular JavaScript objects, also known as object literals or [object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers). JSON object is an intrinsic object in browsers providing methods like `.stringify()`.

Comment: @Teemu , well then good sir or madam. Can you help with my problem?